# Connecting to Tibco using Generated Soap WSDL

Tags: c#, soap, tibco

I have a WSDL generated from Tibco, the WSDL can be imported and run under SoapUI and I can connect without any issue with HTTPS even without Certificate however tried connecting to the same Endpoint using c# I can not connect with the following Code:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.KeepAlive = true;
req.Accept = "gzip,deflate";
req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", soapActionHeader);
req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
req.Method = "POST";
req.Timeout = requestTimeOut;
#endregion

#region Adding XML body to request
Stream strm = null;
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(xmlSOAPTemplate);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}
#endregion

#region HTTP RESPONSE
string resultValue = string.Empty;
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
strm = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(strm);
string res = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
ExceptionHandler.WriteLog($"{url}:Response:{res}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(strm);
```

So, How can we solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

what is the error you're getting ?

Your code seems to manipulate pure HTTP API, while you should use a library that invoke SOAP over HTTP.

I'm no C# programmer, but I googled the subject and found this example (see step 7) : 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/

SOAP can be fairly complex (and especially if you use TIBCO Business Works to produce it with an entreprise project behind), calling it with HTTP API will be complicated.